# How can I export from indesign to photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

We have a layout for a website that was created in indesign (I know this was not what the application was built for). Our frontend developers asked us to export the indesign file to an open psd-file with all the layers available. How can I do that? Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked the Indesign help file yet?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this [How to Save InDesign Files as Layered Photoshop Files](https://indesignsecrets.com/save-indesign-files-layered-photoshop-files.php) could help you.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: Answers that only include a link are not helpful and will be removed if not edited and improved. Please include the relevant information FROM the linked source in the answer itself, and leave the link for attribution and further (but not necessary) information.